# How to extract text starting from a specific word in a string?

Tags: python, regex, strip

So I have tried to extract only the address from this string, but I'm having troubles with it. This is how the string looks like:

```
1040 S. Vintage Ave.
Building A Ontario, CA 91761
United States Phone: 9099725134 Fax: 9099065401

Web: http://www.aareninc.com
```

I want to extract only the text that comes before the word `'Phone'`, so only the address.

I've tried with `strip('Phone')` and then take the first element of an array but it gives me the first letter of that string.

```
address = contacts.strip('Phone')
print(address[0])
```

Comment: `contacts.partition('Phone')[0]` maybe... but that's a rather blunt approach - whether that'll or not for your needs is another thing.

Comment: You need to provide more sample strings. In general, I doubt that a single regex will help and you'd almost certainly need to validate it against a database. But even then you'd probably end up having a lot of false positives.

Comment: @JonClements I love you man !!! It work, as a charm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JonClements commented, the solution is:

```
contacts.partition('Phone')[0]
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you... I doubt it will on more data though... when you try more stuff. Thanks for making it a self answer though... (If you want to credit me for it, then it'd also be nice if you got my name right :p)

Answer (score 1):

Use split function, not strip.

```
address = contacts.split('Phone')
print(address[0])
```

This should work.

Comment: I think because it's all one string, one block of string and if you try split() you will get the first letter of the string

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have something like this with you

`st = '1040 S. Vintage Ave.Building A Ontario, CA 91761 United States Phone: 9099725134 Fax: 9099065401  Web: http://www.aareninc.com'`

```
v = st.split("Phone"))
print(v[0])
```

This will work for Python3.
If you are using Python2 you can avoid using parenthesis with the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

For that task you might use so-called *zero length assertion* (positive lookahead in this case)

```
import re
text = '''1040 S. Vintage Ave.
Building A Ontario, CA 91761
United States Phone: 9099725134 Fax: 9099065401 

Web: http://www.aareninc.com'''
adress = re.findall('.*(?=Phone)',text,re.DOTALL)[0]
print(adress)
```

output

```
1040 S. Vintage Ave.
Building A Ontario, CA 91761
United States
```

Note that it will cause error, if `text` do not contain `Phone` substring. Note `re.DOTALL` flag, so `.` also matches newline character (`/n`), without that flag output would be `Unites States`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works.

Tested on python 2.7

```py
string = r"1040 S. Vintage Ave. Building A Ontario, CA 91761 United States Phone: 9099725134 Fax: 9099065401 Web: http://www.aareninc.com"

f = re.split(' (?=Phone:)', string)

print 'String before Phone:', f[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

using regular expressions:

```
import re
re.split('(Phone)', strng)
['1040 S. Vintage Ave. Building A Ontario, CA 91761 United States ',
'Phone',
': 9099725134 Fax: 9099065401 Web: http://www.aareninc.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your string is defined as:

```
contacts = """1040 S. Vintage Ave.
Building A Ontario, CA 91761
United States Phone: 9099725134 Fax: 9099065401

Web: http://www.aareninc.com"""
```

`contacts.split('Phone')[0]` or `contacts.partition('Phone')[0]` must give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can initially split to get a list of string on both the sides of "Phone".
Then you'd want to use strip to remove leading and trailing white-space.

```
contacts.split('Phone')[0].strip()
```

This works.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is much better to explain how it answers the question.

Comment: I hope the answer is more readable now. Please consider removing the flag from this answer now that I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.search()`:

```
import re

adress = re.search(r'^(.+?)\sPhone', s, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
print(adress.group(1))

# 1040 S. Vintage Ave.
# Building A Ontario, CA 91761
# United States
```